# Response from struts 2 Action class is null in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, struts2

I am facing an issue with struts2+spring MVC+jquery Ajax.
I have a struts2 action class with an Action "uploadLocationData". Here using annotation in struts 2.

```
@Action(value = "uploadLocationData", results = { @Result(name = "success",type = "json") })
    public String insertLocationData() throws Exception {
        String status = locationDao.insertLocationData();
        if(status == "SUCCESS")
        {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
        return ERROR;
        }
    }`
```

`
and the ajax call :

```
function insertData(url,param)
    {
        $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              success : function(data) {
                  console.log(data)
                    if (data == 'SUCCESS' || data == 'success') {
                        alert('Data inserted successfully!!!');
                    }
                    else if (data == 'ERROR' || data == 'error') {
                        alert('Data insertion Failed!!!');
                    }
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    alert('Data insertion Failed!!!');
                },
         });     
    }
```

the issue is, functionality is working but I didn't get the SUCCESS/ERROR response in ajax success/error part.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON responses](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) serialize the action.

We can't see your action, just one tiny chunk.

If `data` is null, then your action has nothing to serialize.